# How to run two separated commands from separated folders using NPM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm separating my project frontend from server side so I have the following folder structure:

```
- client
- server
```

Each folder has its own `package.json` to separate packages. Now from the client folder I have the following command:

```
webpack serve --progress --config webpack.config.development.js
```

And in the server command I have the following command:

```
nodemon server.js
```

I want to run both command at the same time, is there is a way to do this while keeping the same folder structure and separation of packages?

Comment: can you wrap them into a folder and create a .sh and write `cd server && nodemon server.js; cd ../client && webpack serve --progress --config webpack.config.development.js;` into it?

Comment: @MohammadHoseinBalkhani this worked pretty well thank you so much

Comment: no problem, so let me make an answer out of it so anyone can see it. if it is the correct answer for you please mark it as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the folder structure like this:

```
Project/
├─ client/
├─ server/
├─ run.sh
```

run.sh:

```
cd server && nodemon server.js &;
cd ../client && webpack serve --progress --config webpack.config.development.js &;
```

**run the command : `./run.sh`**

> But because we run the applications in the background you need to kill it with `ps -eaf` ( for example `ps -eaf | grep server.js` to search within )

> I think the best way to do all of this is to use a a process manager like [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Comment: Thank you mohammed, I think something is missing this command just runs the first cd server && nodemon server.js; the second gets ignored

Comment: oh wait let me check it

Comment: I edited my answer check it out.
I remember that it's best practice for these kinds of problems that you use process managers. they are all well-managed and easy to use.
btw sorry, I can't mention you with an @ :(